# onRestoreInstanceState does not get called?

Tags: android

I am having a simple code where i want to know when does onRestoreInstanceState get called during program execution in android?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

My first Activity is as follows

```
public class AbcActivity extends Activity {
Button b1;
EditText ed1;
Bundle b = new Bundle();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("Tag", "inside oncreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.v("Tag", "inside onsave instance state");

    outState.putString("key", ed1.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("Tag", "inside on restore instance state");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.v("tag", "inside if");
        String str = savedInstanceState.getString("key");
        ed1.setText("" + str);
    }

}
```

}

my second activity code is as follows

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
Button back;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("Tag", "inside 2 oncreate");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AbcActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.v("Tag", "inside 2 onsave instance state");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("Tag", "inside 2 on restore instance state");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> This method is called after `onStart()` when the activity is being re-initialized from a previously saved state
>   ...
>   This method is called between `onStart()` and `onPostCreate(Bundle)`

This is the case when your `Activity` is re-created after being killed by the system or after a configuration change, and it saved its state in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` - which is always called before an `Activity` is killed.

Comment: so do i need to call finish() or onStop() methods in my code?

Comment: No, it's only called after a disruption to your Activity e.g. after destruction due to a low memory condition. You can "emulate" that by opening the Activity you'd like to test, pressing the Home button, then killing the process e.g. via DDMS (this will send System.exit(1))

Comment: do what Matthias said or just change orientation.

@Matthias that's not the only case, it's called after a configuration change as well.

Comment: Yeah true, we just checked again and it's indeed called in both cases. In any event, it's meant to recover from a disruption such as process termination or a configuration change (e.g. flipping the screen), so it's not meant to be triggered manually by e.g. calling `finish`.